# What is the induction strength of this proof

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Consider the following proof of $(\forall p,n,\sigma) \psi(p,n,\sigma)$
(where $\varphi(n,\sigma):=\forall p\psi(p,n,\sigma)$, is a bounded quantifier formula). We wonder its induction strength.

Proof: Fix $\sigma$. Note that $\varphi(0,\sigma)$. Also note that $(\forall m)\varphi(m-1,\sigma)\rightarrow\varphi(m,\sigma)$.
Thus by induction, we have $\forall m\varphi(m,\sigma)$. Since $\sigma$ is arbitrary,
we have $(\forall m,\sigma)\varphi(m,\sigma)$. i.e., $(\forall p,n,\sigma) \psi(p,n,\sigma)$.
Done proof.

The "note that", "also note" part has no induction.
Is it bounded quantifier formula induction since $\varphi $ is bounded quantifier formula?